# Is it better to be "hung like a pike" or "hung like a stickleback"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang, offensive-language

More from the British movie *The Football Factory*.  The background is that the main character and his best friend have picked up these two girls at a bar; things proceed swimmingly, and the two head over to the girls' house for some hanky-panky.  Unfortunately for the guys, both have imbibed a little too much alcohol, and they promptly pass out in drunken stupor, before any intercourse.  The two girls seem mutually disappointed; one calls out to the other across rooms,

> Shame! He's hung like a pike in 'ere.

And the other replies,

> Good for you. I've got stickleback in 'ere.

I'm guessing the meaning here relates to the properties of the two fish, but I don't know anything about them, and don't understand what *hung* means in this sentence.

Comment: *Hung* is slang for, uh, um, what's the current euphemism? Endowed? Anyway, the size of the male organ. But as for which is better among *pike* or *stickleback*, I got nuttin'.

Comment: The etymology of "hung like a donkey" or "hung like a horse", that is the origin of this phrase is from the Bible. Ezekiel 23:20 "There she lusted after her lovers, whose genitals were like those of donkeys and whose emission was like that of horses." It's actually something that God Himself said here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Hung" in this context means "possessing a penis", with the implication that the penis in question is of some particular size.  "Hung like a horse" or "hung like a mouse" means wielding an organ of (respectively) great or negligible dimensions.

To be hung like some fish means your penis is purportedly comparable not to that fish's penis, but to the whole fish.

A Northern pike (*Esox lucius*), the species of pike most familiar to your average Brit, grows up to 150 centimeters (59 inches) long.  The three-spined stickleback (*Gasterosteus aculeatus*) generally ranges from six to 10 centimeters (two to four inches) long and proportionately slender.

To the original question, which is better, tastes vary but I'm guessing the latter would be innocuous, though perhaps disappointing.  The former would be outright dangerous.

Comment: can I point out that pike is quite tasty?

Comment: @mgb: You don't say...

Comment: You are a master of euphemisms! Great answer.

Comment: @mgb -- you can point it out, but be prepared for the inevitable rejoinder.  @Cerberus -- if you are talking to me, I am unaware of any euphemisms in my response.

Answer (score -1):

Stickleback are very small. Think goldfish size.

Comment: [YMMV](http://i108.photobucket.com/albums/n22/arvomaki/carp/Carp_Ken.jpg)

Comment: Fair enough, but not the mental image most people have when they think of a goldfish.

Comment: Sticklebacks are [even smaller](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaynes/2922311300/) than goldfish. A stickleback is to a goldfish what a goldfish is to a pike.